# How to break page when generating PDF from flutter PDF package

Tags: flutter, pdf, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to generate a pdf using flutter pdf package
[pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf)
,Everything works fine but I want to generate sections on multiple pages below I added sample of my code

`final pdf = pw.Document();`

```
pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
  pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
  build: (pw.Context context) {
    return pw.Center(
      child:Column(
              children:[
                  pw.Text("Hello World"),
                  pw.Text("Hello 2"),
              ]
            )
    ); // Center
  }));
```

How to get Hello World on 1st page and Hello 2 on second page ?

Comment: https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/blob/master/pdf/test/widget_partitions_test.dart
@DavBfr , thanks to him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could just use two multipages like that:

```
pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
  pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
  build: (pw.Context context) {
    return pw.Center(
      child:Column(
              children:[
                  pw.Text("Hello World"),
              ]
            )
    ); // Center
  }));
pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
  pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
  build: (pw.Context context) {
    return pw.Center(
      child:Column(
              children:[
                  pw.Text("Hello 2"),
              ]
            )
    ); // Center
  }));
```

Comment: If i use like that when saving document is it coming as single pdf

Comment: Sure one single pdf. Do you want multiple pdf files?

Comment: No I need it as one.your answer was helpful

Comment: In my case MultiPage only create one page even data is too large that fits in more than one page  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72696248/how-to-add-multipages-for-dynamic-data-in-pdf-flutter