# How to add MultiPages for dynamic data in pdf flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf, multipage

I am trying to print profile data in pdf. For this using this [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package.
Code to generate pdf is as

```
doc.addPage(
pw.MultiPage(
  // pageTheme: pageTheme,
  pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
  build: (pw.Context context) => [
    pw.Partitions(
      children: [
        pw.Partition(
          width: screenWidth * 1.3,
          child: pw.Container(
            height: pageTheme.pageFormat.availableHeight,
            child: pw.Padding(
                 child:pw.Column(children:[//contains multiple items that fits in more than one page]),
                   ),
                ),
             ),

       pw.Partition(
            width: screenWidth * 1.3,
            child: pw.Container(
              height: pageTheme.pageFormat.availableHeight,
                     child: pw.Padding(
                   child:pw.Column(children:[//contains multiple items that fits in more than one page]),
                    ),
                 ),
                ),
],),),
```

**Problem:** in above script only one a4 size page generated and remaining content is ignored.Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to create a list of pdf widgets first using your data. Then pass that list to MultiPage builder and you are good to go.
Here is the example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as p;
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
class MyProfile extends StatelessWidget {
const MyProfile({super.key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('My Profile'),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        //List of pdf widgets
        List<p.Widget> widgets = [];

        //Profile image
        final image = p.ClipOval(
          child: p.Image(
            await imageFromAssetBundle('assets/Image.jpg'),
            fit: p.BoxFit.cover,
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
          ),
        );

        //container for profile image decoration
        final container = p.Center(
          child: p.Container(
            child: image,
            padding: const p.EdgeInsets.all(5),
            decoration: p.BoxDecoration(
              shape: p.BoxShape.circle,
              border: p.Border.all(
                color: PdfColors.blue,
                width: 10,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
        
        //add decorated image container to widgets list
        widgets.add(container);
        widgets.add(p.SizedBox(height: 20));//some space beneath image

        //add all other data which may be in the form of list
        //use a loop to create pdf widget and add it to list
        //one by one
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          widgets.add(
            p.Text(
              'Heading',
              style: p.TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
                fontWeight: p.FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          );
          widgets.add(p.SizedBox(height: 5));
          widgets.add(
            p.Text(
              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed accumsan augue, ut tincidunt lectus. Vestibulum venenatis euismod eros suscipit rhoncus. Sed vulputate congue turpis ut cursus. Proin sollicitudin nulla vel nisi vulputate sagittis. Morbi neque mauris, auctor id posuere eu, egestas porttitor justo. Donec tempus egestas lorem in convallis. Quisque fermentum, augue ut facilisis pretium, risus dolor viverra est, ac consequat tellus risus vitae sapien. ',
              style: const p.TextStyle(color: PdfColors.grey),
            ),
          );
          widgets.add(p.SizedBox(height: 10));
        }

        //pdf document
        final pdf = p.Document();
        pdf.addPage(
          p.MultiPage(
            pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
            build: (context) => widgets,//here goes the widgets list
          ),
        );
        Printing.layoutPdf(
          onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => pdf.save(),
        );
      },
      child: const Text('Print'),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Here is the resulting
[pdf screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1QSg.png)

Cheers :)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you have a full working example for printing multiple pages with data from firebase?

Answer (score 0):

error [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'TooManyPagesException'

> to fix Try to avoid using widgets that do not support pagination, such as Wrap or Column, and use widgets that can span across multiple pages, such as ListView or Table.this working for me .